How can time to execute a manual test case in DevOps be captured?
How can the amount of time required to execute manual test cases in Azure DevOps be captured. For example, I want to use the information in order to provide stakeholders with actionable data for how long a regression will take. Time to execute a given case won't be exact but it will be better than a WAG. I've looked online and I haven't been able to find a means to do this.

In DevOps, manual test case execution still plays a significant role, especially in scenarios where automation might not be feasible or cost-effective, or when exploring new features where test scripts haven't been developed yet. Here are several approaches to capture how much time required to execute manual test effectively:

Manual Time Tracking: Testers manually record the time taken to execute each test case. This can be done using spreadsheets,
time-tracking tools, or built-in features of test management tools.
Test Management Tools: Many test management tools offer features for
tracking the time spent on each test case. Testers can log their time
directly within these tools as they execute test cases.

API Integration: If your test management tool or time-tracking system offers an API, consider integrating it with your
CI/CD pipeline or other relevant tools to automatically
capture test execution time.

Integration with Time-Tracking Systems: Integrate your test management tool with time-tracking systems commonly used in DevOps
environments, such as Jira, Trello, or Asana. This allows automatic
recording of the time spent on test execution tasks.

Automated Test Execution Time: If you have automated tests alongside manual ones, capture the time taken for automated test
execution separately. This helps in understanding the overall testing
time and the portion of it spent on manual testing.

Custom Metrics in DevOps Dashboard: Utilize DevOps dashboards to create custom metrics that track the time taken for manual test
execution. This provides visibility to the entire team and
stakeholders.

Annotations in Version Control Systems: If your test cases are versioned alongside code in a version control system (e.g., Git),
testers can annotate their commits with the time taken to execute
relevant test cases.

Post-Execution Surveys: After completing a test case, testers can be prompted to fill out a brief survey indicating the time taken.
While this is less precise, it can provide valuable insights when
combined with other data.


Azure DevOps provides capabilities for manual test management and execution, detailed time tracking might require some manual effort or integration with external tools. However, by following the steps outlined above, you can effectively track the time taken for manual test case execution within Azure DevOps.
We can also customized the Azure tool with Extensions which offers extensions and integrations that can enhance the test management capabilities, including time tracking. You can explore extensions from the Azure DevOps Marketplace that provide additional features for test management and reporting.
We can also use the Jenkins approach for same and It offers active community support and a robust library of 1400+ plugins.
